# Why my SAP application for Android is being deleted after installation

Tags: android, tizen-web-app, samsung-galaxy-gear, samsung-galaxy

I was playing lately with my Samsung Gear 2 (**not** S2) smartwatch and I have created a new watch-face for it. I would like to show a weather information on it and I have found that for that task I need to use ***Samsung Accessory Protocol*** (SAP).

I followed the Samsung tutorial to create a demo app to learn how to use *SAP*.

I had a problem with deploying Tizen app to my watch but I found out that the lowest currently (2017) available API is 2.3.1 where Gear 2 Smartwatch has 2.2. 
After changing in the *config.xml* the

```
<tizen:application id="XQKp7NYwyM.SimpleSAPConsumer" package="XQKp7NYwyM" required_version="2.3.1"/>
```

to

```
<tizen:application id="XQKp7NYwyM.SimpleSAPConsumer" package="XQKp7NYwyM" required_version="2.2"/>
```

my application was deployed.

I created a certificate to build a signed `wgt` package.

I also created an android provider application according to the tutorial.
Added new certificate and created a signed `apk`.

I copied the `apk` to the Samsung Galaxy S3 phone and tried to install it.
Installation ended without any problem.
However, after some seconds or when I try to initialize the communication from the watch I get the **"Unknown sources"** information from Gear Manager and my app is being deleted.

I already checked "Allow unknown sources" in the android, Gear Manager and allowed USB debugging on the smartwatch (because this is my first question here I am not allowed to post more than 2 links, so I had to give [one link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9lgvipv3yg5ekyw/AADGm8RQo9fUF2b2TxRn_RYja?dl=0) with all screenshots there, sorry).

> Why my application is being deleted and what should I do to have it working correctly.

### Tizen App - Consumer

Build using Tizen Studio 1.1.0.

#### config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/SimpleSAPConsumer" version="1.0.0" viewmodes="maximized">
    <tizen:application id="XQKp7NYwyM.SimpleSAPConsumer" package="XQKp7NYwyM" required_version="2.2"/>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.all"/>
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <tizen:metadata key="AccessoryServiceLocation" value="res/xml/accessoryservices.xml"/>
    <name>SimpleSAPConsumer</name>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/accessoryprotocol"/>
    <tizen:profile name="wearable"/>
</widget>
```

#### accessoryservices.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <application name="HelloAccessoryConsumers">
    <serviceProfile role="consumer" name="sapsample" version="1.0" id="/sample/hello">
    <supportedTransports>
        <transport type="TRANSPORT_BT"/>
        <transport type="TRANSPORT_WIFI"/>
    </supportedTransports>
    <serviceChannel id="123" reliability="enable" priority="low" dataRate="low"> </serviceChannel>
    </serviceProfile>
    </application>
</resources>
```

I can provide rest of the Tizen code (main.js, index.html) if it is needed. Right now I do not think that this has any value to the problem I am facing.

### Android App - Provider

Build using Android Studio 2.2.3
Structure:

```
app
->assets
-->SimpleSapConsumer.wgt
->libs
-->accessory-v2.5.0.jar
-->sdk-1.0.0.jar
->src
-->main
--->java
---->com.sap.baks.sapapp.service
----->SapServiceProvider.java
--->res
---->xml
----->sapservice.xml
---->AndroidManifest.xml
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sap.baks.sapapp">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.accessory.permission.ACCESSORY_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.wmanager.APP"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.wmanager.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service android:name=".service.SAPServiceProvider">
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.RegisterUponInstallReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.samsung.accessory.action.REGISTER_AGENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.ServiceConnectionIndicationBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.samsung.accessory.action.SERVICE_CONNECTION_REQUESTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="AccessoryServicesLocation"
            android:value="/res/xml/sapservices.xml" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="GearAppType"
            android:value="wgt" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

#### sapservice.xml

```
<resources>
    <application name="SAPapp">
        <serviceProfile
            id="/system/sapsample"
            name="sapsample"
            role="provider"
            serviceImpl="com.sap.baks.sapapp.service.SAPServiceProvider"
            version="1.0"
            serviceLimit="ANY"
            serviceTimeout="10">
            <supportedTransports>
                <transport type="TRANSPORT_BT"/>
                <transport type="TRANSPORT_WIFI" />
            </supportedTransports>
            <serviceChannel
                id="123"
                dataRate="low"
                priority="low"
                reliability="enable"/>
        </serviceProfile>
    </application>
 </resources>
```

#### sapserviceprovider.java

I put it together with screenshots because it is quite long.

## ********  EDIT **********

After trying to install sample applications as @Iqbal advised I had the following results:

### Tizen

I was not able to install application on my watch until I changed the API to 2.2. If the API was greater I have seen the following error:

```
[Initializing the launch environment...]
RDS: On
Target information: SM-R380
Application information: Id(VbsgE6bms2.HelloAccessoryConsumer), Package Name(VbsgE6bms2), Project Name(HelloAccessoryConsumer)

[Transferring the package...]
    Transferred the package: wgt stream -> /opt/usr/apps/tmp/HelloAccessoryConsumer.wgt

[Installing the package...]
path is /opt/usr/apps/tmp/HelloAccessoryConsumer.wgt
start process (install)
....
error : 61

end process (fail)
processing result : FATAL_ERROR [61] failed
spend time for pkgcmd is [1537]ms
cmd_ret:61
    An exception occurred
(Installing the package... > Fail)
An exception occurred
Unexpected stop progress...
(8.239 sec)
```

Summary: I have installed the application with API 2.2 and no other changes done.

### Android

Using the sample application without changing anything I was able to run it and connect with the smartwatch! Yupi :) !

But I needed to know why the code I used for the first time was wrong, even if I've got it from Samsung tutorial and website.

I have found that the application is being uninstalled only if I have these lines in *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.accessory.permission.ACCESSORY_FRAMEWORK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.wmanager.APP"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.wmanager.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION"/>
```

If I replaced the lines above with the lines below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.accessory.permission.ACCESSORY_FRAMEWORK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.WATCH_APP_TYPE.Companion" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.wmanager.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION" />
```

everything was OK.

Can someone explain me why it is so?

## ********  EDIT 2 **********

For those who will search for the answer to the question from previous edit.
I have found it [here](https://gearapp.devpost.com/forum_topics/3384-app-rejection-tester-couldn-t-find-the-app-after-installation)

Long story short:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />
```

is the line that has to present - otherwise the app will be deleted from an android device. I have not found this in any documentation to be honest.

Moreover,

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.WATCH_APP_TYPE.Companion" />
```

defines that the smartwatch application will be installed separetly from an android application.
After changing `Companion` to `Integrated` one tells that a smartwatch application is intergrated and will be installed with an android provider app.

Comment: Why are you changing  required_version to 2.2?

Comment: Because when I was using the default one (2.3.1) I always got "cannot deploy" error. I can check it again today evening because I have updated my certificate. Nevertheless, do you think that this can cause the problem for android applicatin being removed?

Comment: 2.2 may not be supported SAP

Comment: I think it does because I can run the app on my smartwatch and it tries to find a provider. Problem is that on the android side the provider app is being removed after installation.

Comment: May be for <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" /> this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow

- [Programming guide](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory/guide) .
- [API Reference.](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory#5)
- Download the sample app from [SAMPLE](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory#1) section and make sure that this sample app is running on your Gear 2 and Android.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Tizen web application cannot be install on my Samsung Gear 2 watch if the API version is not changed to 2.2. After that change I can build and deploy the app. I can run it on my watch and I get no security error. It tries to connect but does not find provider application on the android phone. When I try to install example for android provider I have the error described above. Shortly: On smartwatch works, on android does not :)

Comment: i will try them again today evening and will report me tomorrow with the results.